# Creating a loop from a table depending of the info of another table

Tags: php, mysql

I've a table called "projects":

[image: table projects]

and one other called "user_to_project" that defined which users follow which projects (in this example, the "user_id" 1 follows "project_id" 2,3)

[image: table "user_to_project"]

I'm looking for a function to display all the project following by an user. I was thinking something like this:

```
function getUserProjects($user_id){
    global $db;    
    return $db->query('SELECT * FROM `projects` INNER JOIN `user_to_project` ON (`user_to_project`.`project_id` = `user_to_project`.`user_id`) WHERE `user_to_project`.`user_id` = ' . (int)$user_id );
   
}
```

But it doesn't work...

Comment: Change to `(\`projects\`.\`project_id\` = \`user_to_project\`.\`project_id\`)`

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
  $sql = 'SELECT a.*,b.* FROM `projects` a 
  INNER JOIN `user_to_project` b
  ON (b.project_id = a.project_id) 
  WHERE b.user_id = ' . (int)$user_id;
```